# How can I solve this "ToJson" conversion from dictionary

Tags: c#

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("[");
foreach (var r in dictionary)
{
    sb.Append(r.ToJson);
    sb.Append(",");
}

if (sb.Length > 1)
{
    sb.Length -= 1;
}

sb.Append("]");
sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Please paste the code of ToJson extension.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just serialize it as complete `Dictionary` instead of per item.

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary);
```